# Why does my iOS hardware volume control freeze when starting AVAudioPlayer?

Tags: ios, swift, avaudioplayer, volume

I am using `AVAudioPlayer` to play background music in my app. The strange thing is, I cannot adjust volume with the hardware volume buttons when the music is playing. The volume always 'jumps back' to the original. Here is my code:

```
  do {
     try AVAudioSession.sharedInstance().setCategory(AVAudioSessionCategoryAmbient)
  } catch {    
  }

  self.avplayer = AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)
  self.avplayer?.numberOfLoops = -1
  self.avplayer?.prepareToPlay()
  self.avplayer?.play()
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: You can't play music in the background with an Ambient category.

Comment: I suspect the OP means "ambient music" by "background music" rather than "music in the background." That said, it would be a useful step in exploring the issue to use `...Playback` rather than `...Ambient` and see if that changes the situation. I doubt it will, but it's something I'd always try. I would also add a KVO observer to `avplayer.volume` and `AVAudioSession.shared.outputVolume` to see if there's another part of the code modifying the volume

Comment: I mean "ambient" music, not music playing while the app is in the background.